# Perl ReadParse to process SELECT html tag with multiple options slected

Tags: html, perl

How do I access all the options selected from a SELECT tag which is then passed into a form using POST
The HTML form is setup like this:

```
<div class="header">        
<FORM ACTION=/cgi-local/process.pl METHOD=POST>
<p>
CMS:
</p>
<h6>Hold Down control(CTRL) key to select multiple CMSs</h6>

<SELECT NAME = "cms" multiple>

<option></option>>
<option>#1 - 15 N 0.4 N/O ONTARIO AVE</option>>
<option>#2 - 15 S 1.1 S/O 6TH</option>>
<option>#3 - 215 N CENTRAL 215</option>>
<option>#4 - 215 S 0.45 S/O IOWA</option>>

</SELECT>
</p>
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Submit Form" align="center">

</FORM>
</INPUT>
</div>
```

The Perl portion where it handles the POST data using ReadParse:

```
use CGI qw(:cgi-lib :standard);
&ReadParse(%in);

$cms = $in{"cms"};
```

Displaying the content of `$cms` just shows the first option selected despite multiple selection. How do I access the passed in data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use CGI qw(:cgi-lib :standard);
&ReadParse(%in);
```

Aaaah, the nineties...

> How do I access all the options selected from a `SELECT` tag?

Use [`multi_param`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#Fetching-the-value-or-values-of-a-single-named-parameter):

```
my @v = multi_param('cms');
```

In doing so, you'll be giving up compatibility with Perl 4's `cgi-lib.pl`. That is, don't use `&ReadParse(%in);` Instead, access values of CGI parameters using `param` and ditch the `%in` hash.

According to `perldoc perlhist`, last version of Perl 4 was released in 1993:

> `Larry    4.036         1993-Feb-05     Very stable.`

You may be stuck with an older version of [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI). It was added in 2014. If that is the case, you can use `my @v = param('cms');` but do read the documentation.